# How to turn code into one-line return statement

Tags: python, return, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm using comprehensions to minimize the code. I figured out how to make a comprehension for the list l, but I can't seem to figure out how to make a comprehension for dict d and then transform the two comprehensions to a one-line return statement. Any help would be appreciated!

```
def f(dct:{str:[(str,int,int)]}) -> [str]:
    d = dict()
    for a,b in dct.items():
        count = 0
        for x,y,z in b:
            if y <= -1:
                y = y * -1
            count += y
        d.update({a:count})
        
    l = list()
    for a,count in sorted(d.items(), key=(lambda t:(-t[1],t[0]))):
        l.append(a)
    return l
```

Comment: You seem to have a `return` statement. Is this part of a function? If so, it would be better to show the code as a function along with an example of it being called.

Comment: `for` loops are more powerful than comprehensions: there are a lot of things that can be done only with a loop.

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to turn all create-loop-insert blocks, i.e. *the entire function*, into one line consisting of dict/list comprehensions?

Comment: " ... to minimize the code" - You should rather try to minimize the efforts needed to read and understand it. A comprehension wouldn't be a good idea here anyway, as you have to keep some state in your `count` between items. A comprehension is better adapted when you generate output items that only depend on each individual, independant input item.

Comment: Please be aware that ``d.update({a:count})`` should just be ``d[a] = count``. The ``if y <= -1:`` part can be omitted with just using ``count += abs(y)``. Since the ``count`` only exists to be used in sorting, you can directly store it as *negative* (``count -= abs(y)``) and use ``sorted`` with ``reverse=True``.

Comment: One thing to remember is that source code is read a lot more often than it's written. Consider the future potential readers of your code, will putting it all into a single line make it more complex (time cost) for a potentially marginal improvement in execution time or lines of code?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the equivalent one liner:

```py
def f2(dct):
    return [a for (a,_) in sorted({a:sum(abs(y) for (_,y,_) in b) for (a,b) in dct.items()}.items(), key=(lambda t:(-t[1],t[0])))]
```

This version retains the property that items from the original `dict` which had equivalent sums are sorted in name order.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the following should be equivalent to your function:

```
def f(dct:{str:[(str,int,int)]}) -> [str]:
    counts = {a: sum(abs(y) for (_, y, _) in b) for a, b in dct.items()}
    return sorted(dct, key=lambda a: (-counts[a], a))
```

Note that in general, "fewer lines" is not necessarily better, faster, or more readable. In this case, I'd say those two lines are okay, but making it *one* line, while possible, does not make it better. Changing the name of the dict to `counts` and iterating the values in the original dict in the list comprehension also helps readability IMHO.

Also, you do not really need the first dict, since you need each count just once (and those counts are also computed only once in the `lambda`). This way, it's not too horrible in a single line, either.

```
def f(dct:{str:[(str,int,int)]}) -> [str]:
    return sorted(dct, key=lambda a: (-sum(abs(y) for _,y,_ in dct[a]), a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fold all loops into nested comprehensions. Since the `dict` is never used for key-value access, creating a generator of tuples is simpler; by directly creating the count as negative and storing it first, no `lambda` is needed.

```py
def f(dct: 'Dict[str, List[Tuple[str, int, int]]]') -> 'List[str]':
    return [a for _, a in sorted(((-sum(abs(y) for _, y, _ in b), a) for a, b in dct.items()))]
    #      ^^        ^            ^ ^ invert one item directly to remove the need for a key function
    #      ||        |            + instead of an entire dict[str, int], we create a lazy Generator[Tuple[int, str]]
    #      ||        + invert order since we store name last
    #      |+ the str in the list
    #      + the list we want to return
```

In case it is not clear enough from the code, this should generally be avoided since it is barely readable, least of all comprehensible.

---

A slightly shorter variant:

```py
def f(dct: 'Dict[str, List[Tuple[str, int, int]]]') -> 'List[str]':
    return [*[*zip(*sorted(((-sum(abs(y[1])for y in dct[a]),a)for a in dct))),][1],]
```

In case any sequence of strings is fine as a result:

```py
def f(dct: 'Dict[str, List[Tuple[str, int, int]]]') -> 'Tuple[str]':
    return [*zip(*sorted(((-sum(abs(y[1])for y in dct[a]),a)for a in dct))),][1]
```

Comment: The you would remove the ``-`` before the ``sum``.

Comment: Am I reading your code correctly and seeing that the sort order is by `a` first, then `sum of y`?

Comment: @quamrana You did, just spotted and corrected the error.

Comment: If you need 5 lines of comments to explain one line, you should use more than one line. :-P

Comment: @tobias_k Yeah, might as well write the regular loops. They are shorter if the intention is for anyone to be able to understand the code.